# (About roseus) How can I know about member functions and keyword arguments?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a question about roseus.
In a sample program, there are arguments like
(ros::roseus ... )
(ros::advertise-service ... )

But how can  I get the information about the member functions (and keyword arguments) ?
Or where are these defined ?
This is the example of the sample program.

```
#!/usr/bin/env roseus

(ros::load-ros-manifest "roseus")
(ros::roseus "talker")
(ros::advertise "chatter" std_msgs::string 1)
(ros::rate 100)
(while (ros::ok)
  (setq msg (instance std_msgs::string :init))
  (send msg :data (format nil "hello world ~a" (send (ros::time-now) :sec-nsec)))
  (ros::ros-info "msg [~A]" (send msg :data))
  (ros::publish "chatter" msg)
  (ros::sleep)
)
(ros::roseus "shutdown")
(exit)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198780/(about-roseus)-how-can-i-know-about-member-functions-and-keyword-arguments?/) by [Kaori Furuike](https://answers.ros.org/users/20398/kaori-furuike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-12-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry that currently is is not documented yet, so please refer to https://github.com/jsk-ros-pkg/jsk_roseus/tree/master/roseus/test for example

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2014-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kaori Furuike](https://answers.ros.org/users/20398/kaori-furuike/) on 2014-12-04**:
OK. Thank you for your reply.